# bind all the other three dropdowns based on firstdropdown in cshtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

This code is for binding 2 dropdowns based on the first dropdown. I want all the other three dropdowns to bind based on the first dropdown.

```js
function ByCategory(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Admin/GetItems2',
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      branchname: e
    },
    success: function(subserv) {
      $('#BranchCategory_BranchCategory').html("");
      $('#BranchCategory_BranchCategory').append($('<option></option>').val("0").html("--Select Category--"));

      $.each(subserv, function(i, obj) {
        $('#BranchCategory_BranchCategory').append(
          $('<option></option>').val(obj.BranchCategory).html(obj.BranchCategory));
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML code as well.

Comment: there are 1000s of questions on here about implementing cascading dropdowns (i.e. dropdowns whose values depend on the value of another dropdown). Did you search or try anything?